# Sqlite INSERT to return row id even if exists

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way to incorporate a SELECT statement after an INSERT in the same transaction to get the rowid in a single SQL call?

Scenario: Trying to squeeze / embed SQL part of the code so that there'd be no need to excessively mimic transaction in the code outside SQL with additional SQL statements (I'm using sqlite with JDBC and code is written in scala).

Basic idea: Call INSERT on a column with specific criteria and return the rowid on successful insert. THE CATCH: In case the row already exists, call a SELECT hence return the rowid with same criteria also in that case.

This SQL call embedded in my scala code detects if row with specific criteria already exist. UNFORTUNATELY it does not return the existing rowid in case row with such criteria already exist. Could a CASE or similar in conjunction enable the desired effect (return rowid regardless row exists or it if it has just been inserted)?

```
INSERT INTO keywords (kw)
SELECT ?
EXCEPT
SELECT kw FROM keywords WHERE kw = ?;
```

After this INSERT call I can always have a separate call / transaction calling the statement, but the idea would be that of including SQL logic in single call in case it'd be possible in context of SQL logic.

```
SELECT rowid FROM keywords WHERE kw = ?;
```

Table is created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE keywords
  (kw STRING,
  Timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'NOW', 'LOCALTIME')),
  UNIQUE(kw));
```

Comment: Can you not change the Scala code to return the rowid from select, if it's already doing a select?

Comment: Good question, but the overall idea is to avoid jumping to scala code as the logic should be contained in a single SQL statement as far as possible.

Comment: I don't know if SQLite can offer you what you want and I think it might be best for you to change Scala code.

Comment: Thanks but it really is not what I am looking for, hopefully somebody with Sqlite experience can contribute.